# Running Spring boot app alongside MongoDb in Docker - com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to run my Spring boot project as a dockerised container alongside a MongoDb container both within the same Docker network.

I get the following error

```
 INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
```

I've already set up the Docker network successfully, and created+run the mongodb container:

```
docker run --name=mongotestv1 --rm --network=testnetwork mongotestv1
```

So my understanding is, this pull the mongodb image off of the Docker registry and creates a container that now runs in the Docker network `testnetwork`.

This seems to work, where docker ps shows the container indeed running.

So next I moved to start up my Spring Boot project app itself in the same Docker network:

```
docker run --name=notedemo --rm --network= testnetwork -p 8089:8089 -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongotestv1:27017/dev notedemo
```

This ran fine (ASIDE from the connection errors that popped up alongside the normal Spring app runtime logs).

`Docker ps` now shows both `mongotestv1` and `demo` running.

So I thought that since the mongo container is unable to connect to `localhost:27017`, maybe its due to my other locally brew-installed mongodb community that's already stopped?

So I ran `ps -ef | grep mongod | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d ' '`, `ps -ef | grep mongodb-community | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d ' '` and `brew services list`. both showed that the community version is stopped already with zero matching processe.

Running `ps -ef | grep mongo | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d ' '` showed one process, which I assume is the mongo container.

I've also disabled my antivirus to ensure the firewall wasn't blocking connections.

So `localhost:27017` is definitely not used, why this error?

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/dev
server.port=8089
```

Really stuck here. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you expose Mongo Ports while starting the Mongo Container `-p 27017:27017`

Comment: Sorry, how do you expose the port while starting the mongo container?

Comment: docker run --name=mongotestv1 -p 27017:27017  --rm --network=testnetwork mongotestv1

Comment: I tried that. Still the same issue